# Identity asp.net core 3.0 - IdentityDbContext not found IdentityDbContext<CUser> no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm getting with a couple DbContext errors.
Does anybody has any ideahow to solve that?
.NET Framework
C#, MVC
my code:

````
using CProg.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CProg;

namespace CProg.Data
{
public class CkContext : IdentityDbContext<CUser>
{
public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
.HasKey(e => e.Id)
.Property(e => e.Id)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
.HasRequired(e => e.Author);}}}```
````

Comment: You need to reference the correct package and import it: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: that somewhat worked because the next error starts telling me that OnModelCreating is no suitable method found to override and modelBuilder cannot convert  System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder

Comment: Adding using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework; seems to have helped.